# jquery toggling all divs instead of just one

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of div that I am going to toggle upon click. However, I do not want to have a bunch of different jquery functions to accomplish the same thing. The problem is that my current function will toggle all of the divs as opposed to just the selected one. Any solutions for toggling only the one that is selected without having a bunch of jquery functions?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uq6xcdo5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="help-spacer">
    <div class="help-info">
    <a href="" class="help-info-link"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Hello</a>
    </div>
    <div class="help-info-text" hidden>
        Hello Hello Hello
    </div>
</div>
<div class="help-spacer">
    <div class="help-info">
    <a href="" class="help-info-link"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Hello</a>
    </div>
    <div class="help-info-text" hidden>
        Hello Hello Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.help-info {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
}
.help-info-open {
    background: #1795db;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
}
.help-info-link {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}
.help-info-link-open {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.help-info-text {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".help-info-link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.help-info').toggleClass('help-info-open');
    $('.help-info-link').toggleClass('help-info-link-open');
    $('.help-info-text').toggle();
});
```

Comment: just FYI, you should think about wrapping the entire thing in a div and doing an onclick on that div class, this way it is better for the UI and UX and the entire div is covered when a user clicks and no nasty surprises. Another reason to do this is so that you can do $(event.currentTarget) and manipulate objects from that current Target and all subsequent divs under it without effecting the other divs which have the same class names. This is a nifty trick :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the event handler, *this* refers to the clicked element. So you can do something like this:

```
$(".help-info-link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.help-info').toggleClass('help-info-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('help-info-link-open');
    $(this).closest('.help-info').next('.help-info-text').toggle();
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4q6b0gn4/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closest you could use the direct parent function, and a next function like i've done here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uq6xcdo5/1/

```
$(".help-info-link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('help-info-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('help-info-link-open');
    $(this).parent().next(".help-info-text").toggle();
});
```